# How locally developved flutter plugins are archived and used?

Tags: flutter, devops, artifactory, flutter-dependencies, dependency-management

In Java world maven artifacts can be stored locally in [nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-oss) or [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF).

I see https://pub.dev/ is used for publicly available Flutter plug in. I am wondering how does mobile companies store internally developed artifacts/components and do dependency management.

An additional question is, can plugins be shared using [jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) or [war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a dependency that's stored in a git repository somewhere else:

```
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:munificent/kittens.git
      ref: some-branch
```

Or you can include packages that are on your local filesystem (though this is not recommended in most cases):

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    path: /Users/me/transmogrify
```

Reference: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies

Comment: but if a java artifact is put in artifactory, the sorce code is not made available, what you suggest, will make the source code available. I guess, my queston can be re-worded to say, I only want run time equivalent ( *.class in case of java), not entire code

Comment: Your goal is to be able to provide a package to a third party without making the source code available?

Comment: it is one of the goal